# Generalization of a proposition on vector analysis

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Here is my question:
Suppose there is a map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^4$, say $f$. And it satisfies:
  for any $t$, $f(t)$ and $f'(t)$ are linearly independent; but $f''(t)$ is linearly dependent on $f(t)$ and $f'(t)$. 
Can we prove that the image of this map lives in a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^4$?
In $\mathbb R^3$, this is a proposition seen in many text books, but how can we generalize it to higher dimensions?

Comment: $f$, $f'$ and $f''$ are linearly dependent with coefficients depending on $t$ or independent of $t$?

Comment: They can depend on t.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $f$ is of class $C^2$, with values in $\mathbb R^d$, for any $d\ge2$. Then $f$ satisfies a diff. eq. of the form 
\begin{equation}
 f''(t)=a(t)f'(t)+b(t)f(t),\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $a$ and $b$ are continuous functions. Let $V$ be the linear span of $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$, and let $P$ be a linear projector from $\mathbb R^d$ onto $V$. Let $g(t):=Pf(t)$. Then (1) holds with $g$ in place of $f$, and also $g(0)=f(0)$ and $g'(0)=f'(0)$. So, by the uniqueness of the solution on an initial-value problem, we have $g=f$. Hence $f(t)\in V$ for all $t$, and $V$ is two dimensional, as desired.

**Details on the uniqueness of the solution on an initial-value problem:** Let $h:=f-g$. Then (1) holds with $h$ in place of $f$, and we also have $h(0)=h'(0)=0$. These conditions can be rewritten as 
\begin{equation}
 H'(t)=F(t,H(t)):=A(t)H(t)
\end{equation}
and $H(0)=[0,0]^T$, where $H:=[h,h']^T$, ${}^T$ denotes transposition, and $A(t):=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\b(t)&a(t)\end{bmatrix}$. 
It follows now by [Theorem 2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiuwITGs53bAhWK5YMKHWx-CI8QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Focw.mit.edu%2Fcourses%2Fmathematics%2F18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011%2Funit-iv-first-order-systems%2Fmatrix-exponentials%2FMIT18_03SCF11_s35_2text.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1Yh3q9BO7LZ2KAyapW8b_7) that $H(t)=[0,0]^T$ for all real $t$; that is, $g=f$.

Alternatively, the same conclusion follows by [Main Uniqueness Theorem, page 15](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiuwITGs53bAhWK5YMKHWx-CI8QFgg1MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.washington.edu%2F~burke%2Fcrs%2F555%2F555_notes%2Fexist.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3OQ8dZb9bu5cUAAJO0Seyf). It is straightforward to check all the conditions of that theorem. In particular, the main condition, that $F$ is locally
Lipschitz continuous, follows immediately because $A$ is continuous and $F(t,H(t))=A(t)H(t)$ is linear in $H(t)$.

Comment: I doubt the validity of this argument.  If we change it to " f map from R1 to R2, and f' is linearly depend on  f " , you can still quot this ODE argument to show that the image of f live within a 1 dimension subspace of R2? But this statement is false!

Comment: @YongchenChen : I don't see how I "can still quot this ODE argument to show that the image of f live within a 1 dimension subspace of R2". Can you provide details on that? Also, can you use TeX in your communications on this forum? (You are expected to do so, I think.) On the other hand, the argument in my answer is short and simple. If it seems doubtful to you, can you pinpoint the place(s) you have difficulty with?

Comment: @YongchenChen: why are you saying the statement is false for $f'$ linearly dependent on $f$? If $a(x)$ is a continuous scalar function, the solution to $f'(x)=a(x)f(x)$ for vector valued $f$ lives within a $1$ dimensional subspace. Indeed, it is $f(x)=u(x)f(0)$ with a scalar solution $u(x)$ to $\dot u(x)=a(x)u(x)$, $u(0)=1$.

Comment: There is a simple counterexample for this. For if f starts at (-1, 0), moving toward the origin along the x axis, decelerate to 0 when it hit the origin, then move along y axis.  We can make it such that f and all derivative of f is 0 at the origin.

Comment: I am thinking about the validity of the ODE argument. (I think it's because the existence and uniqueness of ODE is not exactly this form. so you can't quot it in this way)

Comment: @YongchenChen: in your "counterexample", are you sure you can arrange the coefficient $a(x)$ in $f'(t) = a(t) f(t)$ to be continuous? // Regardless, if as in your question $f(t)$ and $f'(t)$ are linearly independent, they must be both non-vanishing. More precisely, the correct analogue is not what you wrote in your first comment, but "if $f$ maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ is such that $f \neq 0$ (this is the "linear independence in one dimension"), and $f'$ is linearly dependent on $f$, then $f$ is one dimensional". This statement is certainly true.

Comment: @YongchenChen : I have added details on the uniqueness, using two alternative sources. Does this convince you enough?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Is anything wrong with this answer?

Comment: @ Pietro Majer @Iosif Pinelis  I am saying that the analogue statement will be false for its one dim analogue, if not assume that f is nowhere vanish. And we can easily use the "smooth but not analytic function' to construct an counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly, your conditions say
$$f''+af'+bf=0$$
with some constants $a,b$.
This is a linear differential equation, so $f(t)=ue^{\lambda t}$, where $u\in R^4$, and $\lambda$ is found from the characteristic equation
$$-\lambda^2+a\lambda+b=0.$$
If the characterictic equation has two roots then 
$$f=ue^{\lambda_1t}+ve^{\lambda_2t},$$
If it has a multiple root then
$$f(t)=(u+vt)e^{\lambda t}.$$
We found all solutions because $u$ and $v$ can be arbitrary vectors.
In both cases $f$ lies in a $2$-dimensional subspace (spanned by $u$ and $v$.)

The argument is independent of the dimension of the space.

Comment: I understood the second sentence of the OP as allowing $a$ and $b$ to depend on $t$.

Comment: I understand what you said. But still fell something is not right... Let me think about it thoroughly for a min, then I'll get to you.